# Not Getting Binaries after Building libjingle

Tags: libjingle

I am trying to build libjingle. I have completed steps mentioned in its README but still i am not getting the binaries.

The steps I followed are:
I used building using GYP
* installed depot-tools
* gclient config http://libjingle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk
* gclient sync
* gclient runhooks
* make

But as mentioned in the last part of README, i should get the binaries under talk/build/dbg/staging or talk/build/opt/staging.
But I am not getting anything in these paths.
Please help me.
Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Hi could you resolve the problem? i am facing the same situation